# В чем различия между "одним запросом" и "одним обращением" к базе в PostgresSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

Начав работать с PostgresSQL я столкнулся с непониманием разницы между понятиями **один запрос**, и **одно обращение к серверу**.

Раньше я думал что если я в конце каждого скрипта ставлю `;` то автоматически получаю два обращения и два запроса, и вообще думал что это синонимы. На пример:

```
INSERT INTO table_01 (...) VALUES (...);

INSERT INTO table_02 (...) VALUES (...);
```

Но тут старшие товарищи подсказали мне что это не синонимы, а разные вещи.

Если я ввожу два разных скрипта за один раз я всегда делаю два обращения? Или нет? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это работает?

1. Что понимать под запросом?
2. Что понимать под обращением?
3. В чем главные различия учет которых принципиален при подключении приложения к базе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) 2)

Если сделать вот так:

```
connection.execute( "INSERT INTO table_01 (...) VALUES (...);" );
connection.execute( "INSERT INTO table_02 (...) VALUES (...);" );
```

это два запроса и два обращения.

А если так:

```
connection.execute( "INSERT INTO table_01 (...) VALUES (...);INSERT INTO table_02 (...) VALUES (...);" );
```

то запросов всё равно два, а обращение одно.

3) В первом случае после каждого execute ты получишь один ответ. Т.е. всего 2 ответа, и в каждом одно "значение". Во втором случае ты получишь один массив (ну не совсем массив, но в данном случае это неважно) из ответов, где их (ответов) будет 2 штуки по одному значению в каждом ответе. Разница - в том, как получить ответы (например, как понять, оба запроса выполнены без ошибок, один - опять же какой именно,- или ни одного).

А принципиально - надо начинать с проверки, может ли вообще коннектор обслужить мультизапросы.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что запрос- это когда ты шлешь на сервер свои инструкции.

Соответственно, если ты шлешь пакет запросов из 2-ух инструкций(как в примере), то ты говоришь серверу "выполни вот это"=> это одно обращение на сервер.

Сервер же раскрывает данный пакет на своей стороне и выполняет 2 запроса.

Answer (score 2):

### Общее понятие

Давайте посмотрим общий смысл слова запрос:

> **запрос это:**
>
> 1) Обращение с требованием, просьбой дать какие-л.
>   сведения, объяснения и т.п  по какому-н. делу.

Если мы будем углубляться в употребление этого слова, то вероятно придем к выводу, что в одном обращении к чему-то либо, может быть несколько запросов, если есть такая возможность.

Хотя по сути, в общем употреблении это практический синонимы.

### Аналогия в реальной жизни

Приведем аналогию с человеком, предположим, вы хотите побеспокоить кого-либо со своим вопросом. Подходите к человеку и говорите:

- Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могу найти ближайшую кофейню?

Сколько здесь обращений и запросов? Правильно одно! Вы же один раз обратились к человеку.

- Подскажите пожалуйста, где я могу найти ближайшую кофейню? А еще меня интересует где здесь есть музей?

Ага, до сих пор одно обращение к человеку, но запросов уже два. Тогда рассмотрим ситуацию с другого плана:

- Подскажите, где я могу найти ближайшую кофейню?
- Ближайшая кофейня находится в конце данной улицы
- Спасибо! Подскажите еще, где я могу найти продуктовый магазин?

Сколько обращений и запросов вы сделали к человеку? По два. Все верно.

### База данных

Так же это работает в базе данных, вы обращаетесь к базе, но можете отправить одновременно несколько запросов за **одно обращение**, чтобы сократить издержки на передачу данных, если для этого есть возможность в драйвере, если от выполнения этого запроса не зависят дальнейшие действия в коде.

Если запросов много на INSERT, то вероятно лучше их уместить в одну конструкцию, чтобы ускорить вставку.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4);
```

Если конечно это поддерживается синтаксисом базы данных, тогда будет один запрос и одно обращение.